# Is there the way to resolve RAM problems?

Tags: macbook-pro, upgrade, memory

I have Macbook Pro 13" Late 2011. It has 4GB RAM, i bought 2x8GB Corsair, CMSO8GX3M1A1333C9. It works cool in 98% of time, but when i play games or use very heavy apps like Photoshop, i always get crashes and reboots. I try to use only one slot with 8GB in there – the same problem. On 4GB (2x2GB) no crashes or reboots but it's mush more slower...

The questions are:
– how to resolve that problems?
– may it be that my Mac can't use more than 4GB in one slot?
– what memory will make work with my Mac stable?

Best regards,
Sergey

Answer (score 1):

Did you buy the RAM from a provider that guarantees it for Macintosh systems? I've gotten RAM from a big box store that has met the exact specifications, but wouldn't work in my Mac Book Pro without crashing all of the time. I ended up returning that RAM and getting it for about the same price from a vendor that guarantees it will work in my specific system.

Apple specs say that this machine is capable of a maximum of 8GB of ram, but third parties have found, that with the right modules, 16GB works fine.

I'd recommend returning your current RAM modules and getting new ones from a Mac specialist. I don't think that the modules you have will ever work with your hardware.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I didn't buy it from provider that guarantees it for Macintosh systems, i checked only comments at that store. People say that it's perfect with Mac. I'd like to return it, but the problem is that is now my problem because there is no guarantees from store. As Alistair McMillan advice, i'll try to make memtest, maybe there is problems with my items, so i can return it by warranty.

Comment: Most stores will accept returns as long as it is not damaged. Check the store's return policy.

Comment: It's Russia) In there, i can return my product only before 30 day after buy and if there is no "signs of wear". I bought my memory half year ago..

Comment: Then you are up pretty late, Google tells me it's currently 4:41am in Moscow right now. I'd suggest trying to sell it to a somebody with a PC. There tolerances are not at tight as Apple's and it will probably work fine in a PC. My recommendation for where to buy Macintosh upgrades probably won't do you any good either.

Comment: I am agree with you. Will try to sell it, ehhh..Thank you one more time. P.S. 20:47 right now in Moscow)

Answer (score 0):

I would test the RAM to make sure it isn't faulty. There are various applications to let you test your RAM. Memtest is a free one you can download [here](http://static.command-tab.com/2008/memtest_422.zip).

Just run the installer, then open a Terminal and type "memtest all" to run the test. It will run the test multiple times and might take an hour or two to run completely, but it will tell you if it finds any errors.

More information here: http://www.command-tab.com/2008/01/11/how-to-test-ram-under-mac-os-x/